# Questions regarding a logic about Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

How to make the system automatically run a method every 5 seconds. Being that this frame is not the focus, it can be a JDialog with the focus, so the process can be executed?
Thank you!

Comment: what have you tried? why didn't it work? Stackoverflow works best when you have a more specific question, not when you want a tutorial-like guidance

Comment: what are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I do not know if the system will run this process with the frame in the frame? Cause I need the process to continue being done as the User uses the other frames of the system ..

Answer (score 1):

Use a Swing `Timer`. Create one, add an action listener for it, then start it, and the action listener will be invoked periodically. For example:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(500);
timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        // this runs every 500 milliseconds
    }
}
timer.start()
```

Comment: Does that timer object do the right thing sending the UI updates to the EVT ?

Comment: No. You need to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

Comment: @tbodt  "Although all Timers perform their waiting using a single, shared thread (created by the first Timer object that executes), the action event handlers for Timers execute on another thread -- the event-dispatching thread. This means that the action handlers for Timers can safely perform operations on Swing components. However, it also means that the handlers must execute quickly to keep the GUI responsive." (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

Comment: thanks, tbodt but where I put this code in the constructor? And he will run even if the frame is in the background of a JDialog?

Comment: You can construct it any time you want, but only start it when you actually want to start it. It will continue to run until you call `timer.stop()`, even if there is a modal dialog on top of it.

Comment: `javax.swing.Timer` is a good choice, but the constructor requires _two_ parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can spawn a new thread and make it sleep 5 seconds in a loop.

But you'd rather go with a scheduling library like Quartz (Spring has one too) if you have more complex needs.
Because you don't want to spawn 100 threads, all sleeping 5 seconds, but you rather want to have 1 scheduler thread triggering multiple worker threads.

Comment: No. Adding quartz does not make sense in such a small and focused task. timer is more suitable here

Comment: @DavidHofmann that's why I said "if you have more complex needs" :)